# How to override Show field in sonata admin

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin

I want show the list of multiple attributes Name => value in a table overriding single field of only for `PortsAdmin` in `ShowMapper`

`Ports` Entity mapped with `PortsAttributes` Entity.

Relation of entity is `OneToMany` Ports with multiple attributes.

**Admin View (Edit Action)**

[image: Edit View of attributes listing]

**Show Action**

[image: Show list of attributes]

> I want change attribute view same as edit Action.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can create a custom template for the `PostAttributes`:

Example:

```php
/* ShowMapper in admin */
$showMapper->add('attributes', null, array(
    'template' => 'YOUR_TEMPLATE.html.twig' // <-- This is the trick
));
```

In your template, you can extend the base show field (`SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:base_show_field.html.twig` or `@SonataAdmin/CRUD/base_show_field.html.twig` for symfony > 4.0), and override the `field` block. The variable named `value` stores the data in twig.

Example:

YOUR_TEMPLATE.html.twig

```
{% extends 'SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:base_show_field.html.twig' %}
{# for sf > 4.0 #}
{#  {% extends '@SonataAdmin/CRUD/base_show_field.html.twig' %} #}

{% block field %}
    {% for val in value %}
        {{ val.name }} - {{ val.value }} {# I'm just guessing the object properties #}
        <br/>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: I have tried the same trick and it didn't work ! I'm using symfony 3.4 and this `template` attribute works only with symfony 3.1 is there another way to override  the `show_field` view ?

Answer (score 0):

@SlimenTN you can try changing this line in template file:

```
{% extends 'SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:base_show_field.html.twig' %}
```

with this:

```
{% extends '@SonataAdmin/CRUD/base_show_field.html.twig' %}
```

The rest of code seems ok (I have the same in a SF4 project)